# Need to remove the empty element creating and add the list

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I'm having three types of input for the single XSL. I have wrote the XSL for the two types. But I got struck for the third type

Input XML file of type 1:

```
<Description>School</Description>
```

Input XML file of type 2:

```
<Description>School
<Text>Time</Text></Description>
```

Input XML file of type 3:

```
<Description>School
<List type="bullet">
<ListItem>Date</ListItem>
<ListItem>Time</ListItem>
</List>
<Text>Push</Text></Description>
```

I have tried the XSL for type 1 and type 2 and it's working well:

```
<xsl:template match="Description">
        <def>
            <para>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(node()[1])"/>
            <def>
                <xsl:value-of select="Text"/>
            </def></para>
        </def>
    </xsl:template>
```

But for the type 1, empty element getting creating and I need to cover all the elements.

Excepted Output would be:

```
   <def>
        <para>School
        <list>
            <listitem><para>Date</para></listitem>
            <listitem><para>Time</para></listitem>
        </list>
            <def>Push</def>
        </para>
    </def>
```

And also I want to remove the empty element in the output for type 1 and type 2.

Comment: So what are the rules for transformation you want to implement? Do you want to map each `Description` container element to a `def` container containing another `para` container containing the transformation of the `Description`s content? Then write a template `<xsl:template match="Description"><def><para><xsl:apply-templates/></para></def></xsl:template>` and set up further templates for the other elements, perhaps `<xsl:template match="List"><list><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` and so on. I am not quite sure when you want to wrap text into a `para` and when not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal use of XSLT is to set up templates processing the nodes you want to transform, each template processing the transformation for a particular element or node type in general, and to use `xsl:apply-templates` to keep processing the children or other relevant nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
      <def>
          <para>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </para>
      </def>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="List">
       <list>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ListItem">
        <listitem>
            <para>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </para>
        </listitem>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Text">
        <def>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </def>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can set it in action for your three samples at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGL/0, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGL/1, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdGL/2.

Comment: I'm using XSL 2.0 version. So the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` code is not validating

Comment: @ScottDon, in XSLT 2 you need to replace that `xsl:mode` declaration with the spelled out identity transformation template `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.